# to have a javascript code only added once when using partial view

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-partialview

i have a partial view that itself is inside a partial view. The content inside the inner most partial view can be rendered multiple times. i have a javascript code that is significant only for the innermost view. SO what happens is when the content is rendered more than once the javascript code is added twice  and event are called twice. e.g

```
var isDccmAndReady = '@isDccmAndReady';

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        $("input[name='ReportDate']").change(function() {
            if (isDccmAndReady) {
                var d = new Date();
                var currentDate = (d.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + +d.getDate() + "/" + d.getFullYear();

                var dateSelected = $(this).val();

                if (new Date(dateSelected) > new Date(currentDate)) {
                    var answer = confirm("The contract has been already reported, are you sure you wish to continue?");
                if (answer) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    $(this).val('@Model.OriginalReportDate.Value.ToShortDateString()');
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Now if the textbox is embedded twice onchange event is called two times when something changes in one of the textbox. how to circumvent this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what you want, if you want a function to run only exactly once, you can use underscore "once" function:

```
var newfunction = _.once(yourfunction);
newfunction();
newfunction();
```

if your purpose is to prevent the event handler to add more than once in an element, you can first unbind the event and then bind it again like:

```
$("#someselector").unbind("change").change(function(){
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working. i added the following javascript in the partial view where the innermost partial is called so that javascript s registered in the dom once.i also added couple of data attributes in the text box whose value i needed in the javascript

> ```
> $(document).ready(function () {
>
>     $(function () {
>         $("input[name='ReportDate']").change(function () {
>
>             if ($(this).attr('data-isDccmAndReady')) {
>
>                 var d = new Date();
>                 var currentDate = (d.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + +d.getDate() + "/" + d.getFullYear();
>
>                 var dateSelected = $(this).val();
>
>                 if (new Date(dateSelected) > new Date(currentDate)) {
>                     var answer = confirm("The contract has been already reported, are you sure you wish to continue?");
>
>                     if (answer) {
>                         return true;
>                     } else {
>                         $(this).val($(this).attr('data-originalReportDateVal'));
>                         return false;
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
>
>             return false;
>         });
>     });
>
> });
> ```